# State change does not effect React DOM

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material UI. For loading purposes, I decided to use Skeleton structure. However, state change does not effect skeleton component's width and height so that it does not work properly.

```
export default function ComplexGrid(props) {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  const [article, setArticle] = useState("");
  const [year, setYear] = useState("");
  const [month, setMonth] = useState("");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(null);

  const skeletonStructure = useRef(null);

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.mainNew[0]) {
      setArticle(props.mainNew[0]);
      setYear(String(article.updated_at).split("-")[0]);
      setMonth(String(article.updated_at).split("-")[1]);
    }

    if (skeletonStructure.current) {
      setWidth(skeletonStructure.current.offsetWidth);
      setHeight(skeletonStructure.current.offsetHeight);
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoaded(true);
    }, 500);
  });

  const stylehvr = loaded && hover && article ? { cursor: "pointer", opacity: "60%", transition: "all 0.5s linear" } : {};
  const hoverbck = loaded && hover && article ? { backgroundColor: "black", cursor: "pointer" } : {};

  return (
    <div className={classes.root} onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)} onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grd}>
        <div style={hoverbck}>
          {article && loaded ? (
            <img ref={skeletonStructure} className={classes.img} style={stylehvr} alt={article.title} src={article.img1} />
          ) : (
            <Skeleton variant="rect" width={width} height={height} animation="pulse" />
          )}

          {article && loaded ? (
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1" className={classes.title}>
              {article.title} - {width} - {height}
            </Typography>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}

          {article && loaded ? (
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" className={classes.date}>
              {month} / {year}
            </Typography>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}

          {article && loaded ? (
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" className={classes.timer}>
              {article.read_time} Dakikalık Okuma
            </Typography>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}

          {article && loaded ? (
            <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.type}>
              {article.content_type}
            </Typography>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since initial state of height and weight are 'null', skeleton does not work as intended, nevertheless weight and height are correctly set in useEffect. How to use correct state for skeleton component?

Comment: set dependency for useEffect otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I think you are needing [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect). Also, you didn't post all of your code, which can be frustrating when we want to help you. Just be careful not to trim too much before you post.

Comment: skeletonStructure.current is null, so it would never setWidth or setHeight, correct? Additionally, useEffect would run every single update causing a recursion issue if you don't add a dependency.

Comment: @ErikOverflow - on the contrary, useEffect would never run on subsequent updates because the code he posted has no dependencies. Honestly, I think the OP failed to show us the entire picture as the code above is invalid/incomplete JS.

Comment: Your sample code is missing a closing paren `)` at the end of your useEffect call and you seem to have an extra `}` in your return.

Comment: @RyanWheale I thought it would only run once is there was an empty array of dependencies? Maybe it runs every time.

Comment: I can set width and height. I checked it React Developer Tools. But, somehow React uses initial state, in other words it does not wait state to be updated.

Comment: Also, I cannot use dependency array because in useEffect there are other codes which I want to run several times. Probably, it is not correct way to do but if I add dependency array, these codes are not executed because they are depend on props.

Comment: @rayhatfield this code is just for demonstration purposes, I accidently forgot to add that. In actual code, there is closing paren sorry for confusion.

Comment: it's impossible to help you without the full code. You obviously removed some code, and in doing so you posted invalid code, which is distracting from being able to help you. Please post your entire code. @ErikOverflow - `useEffect` (and `useMemo`) will only run if (and only if) one of the passed dependencies changes. If you don't pass any dependencies, it will run once and never run again (react will also complain).

Comment: I tried to be as precise as possible, but it created distration. I fixed the code. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @RyanWheale I've tried ```useLayoutEffect``` but it did not work as well. I cannot figure out what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all your states as dependency in the `useEffect` hooks

```
useEffect(() => {//your code}, [//all states here])
```

Comment: I've tried to add dependencies, but I did not work.

Comment: instead of calling setState, can you try `console.log` all the data to see if you actually receive them

Comment: I actually received all the data.

Comment: can you update your code with the new `useEffect` hooks

Comment: My purpose is creating responsive Skeleton structure, so that I should get element's width and height at the current window size. I've actually set them as it can be seen react developer tools. The problem is skeleton width and height use initial state even though these states are updated.

Answer (score 0):

To give dependency to `UseEffect` You need to give it like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //your code which should be executed when dependent state updates.
}, [state names])

//UPDATED 
useEffect(() => {
 if(props.mainNew[0]){
    setArticle(props.mainNew[0])
    setYear(String(article.updated_at).split("-")[0])
    setMonth(String(article.updated_at).split("-")[1])
 }

 if(skeletonStructure.current){
   setWidth(skeletonStructure.current.offsetWidth)
   setHeight(skeletonStructure.current.offsetHeight)
 }

  setTimeout(() => {
   setLoaded(true)
   }, 500) 
 
},[skeletonStructure.current,props.mainNew[0]])
```

if you don't provide dependent states within `[]` then it will not be rendered again when state update occurs. and if you provide `[]` empty then `use-effect` will be called once only.

Comment: Giving dependency somehow breaks the code, is it because ```useEffect``` depends on ```props```?

Comment: if you're using props, then you must provide that too as a dependency. try providing `[props.mainNew[0]]` to `useEffect`

Comment: I don't know the reason but giving dependencies causes states not to be set.

Comment: Ohh i get it. You're making useEffect dependent on the states and updating the states in useEffect. that will cause infinite update error. you just need to set your states somewhere else.

Comment: I've also tried ```useLayoutEffect``` to set the state, but it did not also cure my problem. Do you have any suggestions where I can actually set the state.

Comment: Thank you for effort, but as I said giving these dependencies breaks the code. The problem is ```Skeleton``` uses initial state not the updated state. However, I can see the width and height state are actually updated.